# Given an HtmlUnit HtmlPage object, how do I get the URI of its Document?

Tags: htmlunit

The page object I have is the result of a long chain of `click()` calls (just in case you were wondering how I could have a page object without knowing the URL used to obtain it).

- The method `HtmlPage.getDocumentURI` is not implemented.
- `HtmlPage.getOwnerDocument` returns null.
- `page.executeJavaScript("return document.location").getJavaScriptResult()` also returns  null.

Any hints?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is of course to realize that `executeJavaScript` should have been called `evalJavaScript`, and write something like

```
page.executeJavaScript("document.location").getJavaScriptResult()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
page.getUrl()
```

worked fine for me.